# How to get a stream of an in memory string?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, onedrive

I have a `string` of data, I want to have a `stream` of it without saving it to storage as a file and then getting an stream of it. then I will send this stream to SkyDrive. anyway.

```
await client.UploadAsync(folderId, filename, stream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
```

Is there anyway to get a `stream` of an in-memory string value, without saving it to storage first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write it into a `MemoryStream`:

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(yourString);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    await client.UploadAsync(folderId, filename, stream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) class. You could load it like this for example:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Here is my string."));
```

or, you can just `Write` new data to it like this:

```
var myString = "Hello, World!";
stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString), 0, myString.Length);
```

You could of course use a different encoding if you needed to, say `UTF8` for example.

Comment: +1 but the next time I lose an `è`, I'll know that the fault is yours that suggest as first option the ASCII encoding :-)

Comment: @xanatos, yeah I just don't do much in the way of `UTF8` because I don't deal with global applications. Sorry. :(

Comment: +1. but I try to stay far of encoding in my life!. thanks for your help.